# Async wait until form is loaded to continue

Tags: c#, task

I am trying to get my form to wait until a particular part of my `_Load` method is finished before continuing. I have a few methods that are async, but I cannot figure out why I am not able to get the code to wait until `fakeClickCheckUpdate` is finished before continuing. Here are the main methods involved:

```
public myForm(string args)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Load += myForm_Load;       
}

private void myForm_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    this.fakeClickCheckUpdate();
    loadFinished = true;
    if (this.needsUpdate == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Needs update...");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("update is false");
    }
}

public void fakeClickCheckUpdate()
{
    this.checkUpdateButton.PerformClick();
}

private async void checkUpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo);
    await checkVersion();
    Console.WriteLine(needsUpdate);
}


private async Task checkVersion()
{
    string currVersion;
    string newVersion;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(currVersionTxt))
    {
        currVersion = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    using (StreamReader nr = new StreamReader(versionSaveTo))
    {
        newVersion = nr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    if (!newVersion.Equals(currVersion, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            progressLabel.Text = "New version available! Please select 'Force Download'";
        });
        this.needsUpdate = true;

    }
    else
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            progressLabel.Text = "Your version is up-to-date. No need to update.";
        });
        this.needsUpdate = false;
    }


}
```

Basically, I want it to check the current version with `checkVersion` and finish that before it tries to continue past `loadFinished = true` inside of `myForm_Load`. I have `checkVersion` set as an async Task so that the button click can use `await` on it. Is there any way to get the functionality I need with this code?

Comment: Do you explicitly have to call `PerformClick`?

Comment: "I have checkVersion set as an async Task so that the button click can use await on it.", that logic is backwards. You `await` because something is `async Task`, but why is it `async Task` in the first place and not just `void`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, move your code out of your perform click action.

```
private async void checkUpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CheckForUpdate();
}

private async Task CheckForUpdate()
{
    await startDownload(versionLink, versionSaveTo);
    await checkVersion();
    Console.WriteLine(needsUpdate);
}
```

You can then call that same function in your OnLoad.

```
private async void myForm_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    await CheckForUpdate();
    loadFinished = true;
    if (this.needsUpdate == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Needs update...");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("update is false");
    }
}
```